# Linux Dialog menu items loop

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, dialog

Is possible tell the Linux `dialog` system to jump from the last menu item to the first or *vice versa* when the user has reached the top or bottom item, respectively, using the arrow key? Just like infinite loop if I will hold arrow on keyboard. I was searching but nothing came out.

EDIT:

```
dialog_menu_exit=$(dialog --title "Root: $menurootprivileges | Mod: $modmenu" --menu "Network analyse program example" 15 50 8 \
      "1" "Test 1" \
      "2" "Test 2" \
      "3" "Test 3" \
      "4" "Configuration" \
      "5" "Reset/Reconfiguration" \
      "6" "Exit" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

Now how to jump from the item 6 (Exit) to the item 1 (Test 1) or vice versa?
*I tried post image but can't because of my reputation.*

Comment: The answer is: *yes it is possible* and *it depends upon the menu system*. Are you trying to write a bash script that presents a menu with such a property? The context is very unclear, and the answer to your question depends upon the context.

Comment: Yes I do. I am working on little "script program" for network analyse and I like to have this feature. It is just static menu defined like this:
`dialogmenu=$(dialog --menu <text> <height> <width> <menu height> <tag1> <item1> 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)`

Comment: No, dialog does not wrap around in a list when you reach the end.